# adding signature in mail by php

Tags: php

I want to add signature like gmail in my message body in my php mail script.That signature should show when somebody open to read my mail.Similar to gmail.But when i am attaching image in message variable and sending mal to gmail this is not appearing directly.To watch the signature i would have to click on link "display image" in gmail.Any other idea to show this signature image directly from php mail.
Thanks

Comment: You will need to generate a HTML E-Mail. Voting to close as a duplicate of a question that should give you all the info you need

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed images in html email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851728/how-to-embed-images-in-html-email)

Comment: To clarify, you're sending e-mail from your own PHP script (which has no connection to GMail) and you're putting an `<img />` tag in that message. Then, when you receive the message at your GMail account, you have to click the "Display Images" link to see the image?

Answer (score 2):

A signature is just a part of an email. For plain text mails it is usually separated by a line containing "-- " (that's dash dash space), however, some mail services use different separators. If you want to use images in your signature you need to compose a HTML mail since the signature is nothing else than some part of the message.