# How to embed images in an email

Tags: android, email

How to share a image in email through android. The image should display in the message body.

Thanks,

Yuvaraj.K

Comment: I want to share the image in email through android. While sharing process the image is not embedded in the message body instead of it the image come as attachment to the mail. But my requirement is want to share the image in message body.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed images in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

Answer (score 0):

you can't place it in the body with the standard email app. you can only have it as an attachment.