# Send Email from C# using Outlook's

Tags: c#

i want to write application who send email using outlook and i found [this](http://jptarqu.blogspot.com/2010/06/send-email-from-c-using-outlooks-com.html) link.
i try this and it's perfect for me but the only thing that i miss here is the option to attach files to the mail, is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Have you tried? What have you tried? Did it work?

Comment: Any reason you specifically use Outlook interop over MailMessage?

Comment: no, i only looking for a automatic way to send email using outlook, u know better way ?

Comment: Cool question. here's what i found
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/5168732#5168732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better use MailMessage instead.
There's an example on how to use it with attachment here(Scroll down to "Examples"):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Not only will you get a managed framework for sending mails, but also whoever runs the code will not need Outlook installed and running.

Comment: string server mean my SMTP server ?

Comment: after send the email i see with wireshark smtp packets but the email did not arrive

Answer (score 2):

If you're stuck with outlook for some reason, try this:

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


int pos = (int)email.Body.Length + 1;
int attType = (int)Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;
email.Attachments.Add("file.txt", attType, pos, "File description.");
```

where:

```
Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)_outlookAppInstance.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Comment: Horrid thing to have to do. +1 for effort!