# how to send embed images in email using php and html

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

i know this question is asked several time and it is basic question but i searched last three days but i am still unable to send images in email.please help how can i embed images in my email that is which headers should i include in headers
i write the following code.

```
 $to = "example@gmail.com";
 $subject = "new account created";
 $body = "New account has been created 
 <img border=’0' src=’http://www.example.com/myimages/track.php?MID=1111&SID=2222'  width=’1' height=’1'>
  " ;

 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: admin@gmail.com";  

 $neww=mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: Many users don't like you spying them and so they block your picture - good so!

Answer (score 4):

The reason you can't see your images in email is most email readers stript them out since they can be used for verifying valid email addresses which is a common tactic used by spammers. Your code screams tracking which only proves the point.

There is no way around this as the image filtering is done by the email clients and cannot be controlled by any code you write.

Comment: @johm  conde currently for testing i send emails to myself account but there is not option come which say images are there,i know images are not display by default.but i am unable to send images,as i tell you in above code any error or mistake

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/18008898#18008898).

I posted a solution whereby you could use *Mozilla Thunderbird* to fetch the html image code for you which you can place in your script.  The image will be embedded and would depend on no links or external content.

Look for my answer with the big screenshot of a lizard.

But, even despite that, users can still block images of all kinds. But emebedded images might be considered more acceptable than linked content - it depends on the client as to how images are handled.