# How can I display images in mail content?

Tags: c#, email, webmail

I want send e-mail with some images in content. I think I must attached this images as attachments to e-mail, but my proble is **how can I use attached images in mail content?**

**CODE WHICH SEND MAIL**

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "my.smtp.server";
WebMail.Send(
        clientEmail,
        subject,
        "<html><head></head><body><img src='???' /></body></html>",
        myEmail,
        null,
        new List<string> () { "path" },
        true
    );
```

What I must write as `src` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed images in email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also good sample at http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx

System.Net.Mail.Message Class :

Sample ;

```
var msg = new System.Net.Mail.Message();
msg.isHTML=true;
msg.Body ="<img src=\"cid:IMG1CONTENT\">";


Attachment mya = new Attachment("file-path-here");
mya.ContentId="IMG1CONTENT";
msg.Attachments.Add(mya);
```

You can find more details @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To display the images in email content, one solution is to have an absolute URL. Upload the images to your server and use the abosoluter url as the src attribute value

```
<img src='http://www.yourdomain.com/youfolder/image.jpg' alt='your image desc'/>
```

But some email clients will disable external images. So user may need to enable "show images" when propmpted so.

Comment: Yes I know I can display it in this way but I asked about how I can display attached files in content.