# How to send a email with a base64 embedded image

Tags: html, image, delphi, email, mime-types

**Scenario:** I have a delphi 7 application and i have a function that send mail's with embedded images using base64 encoding, and MIME types.

**The body of the email:**

```html
the message
<hr>
<img width=213 height=120 src="cid:CidKey"/> <!-- Important! here is the cid reffered to the cid that i previously set on the code! -->
<hr>
some text
```

**Problem:** The email comes to me in my Gmail with a gray box instead of a image.

**What i've tried:** I tried to change the MIME: `Content-Type` and etc, to many types such as `text/html` and `image/jpeg`, `alternative/mixed` etc...

**What do i want:** I want to simply send a email that can have a signature(some text) containing a visible image in base64 properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures

Comment: Not a duplicate. The question you mentioned the image are not base64 and the language of development is php not delphi

Comment: but the MIME part is interesting and useful, thanks for it.

Comment: Please paste body of one of your emails with image attachment that you are having issue with.

Comment: Which tcp lib do you use to create mails? Overbyte ICS? Indy? Ararat Synapse?

Comment: @Arioch'The i don't really know this because was not me the author of the mail functions, because here im my work we have many programmers.. but the mail comes ok, and now i found the solution via MIME as you see on the answer but thanks !

Comment: @MarcusAdams i did, but too, i already have found the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution by myself, and the problem was with the MIME.

Before, i was sending the email with only one MIME type that was: `Content-type: text/html`

And now, i created a `TMimeMess` containing `TMimepart`'s as `Multiparts`:

```delphi
var
  m               : TMimemess;
  SubPartSignature,
  mix             ,
  rel             : TMimepart;

  m := TMimemess.create;

  mix := m.AddPartMultipart('mixed',nil);
  rel := m.AddPartMultipart('related', mix);

  m.AddPartHTML(FstlMensagemHTML, mix);//note that the FstlHTMLMessage is the body html of the email
  SubPartSignature := m.AddPartHTMLBinary(cprdbutils.getBlob_StringStream(dts.FieldByName('bl_logo')), 'logo.jpg',   'CidKey', rel);
  rel.AddSubPart;
  rel.AssignSubParts(SubPartSignature);
```

The function `cprdbutils.getBlob_StringStream(dts.FieldByName('bl_logo'))` returns the Stream of the image from the database blob field.

And the function `AddPartHTMLBinary()` is here:

```delphi
function TMimeMess.AddPartHTMLBinary(const Stream: TStream; const FileName, Cid: string; const PartParent: TMimePart): TMimepart;
begin
  Result := AddPart(PartParent);
  Result.DecodedLines.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  Result.MimeTypeFromExt(FileName);
  Result.Description := 'Included file: ' + FileName;
  Result.Disposition := 'inline';
  Result.ContentID := Cid;
  Result.FileName := FileName;
  Result.EncodingCode := ME_BASE64; //this is a constant containing base64
  Result.EncodePart;
  Result.EncodePartHeader;
end;
```

And here is the body HTML of the email:

```html
the message
<hr>
<img width=213 height=120 src="cid:CidKey"/> <!-- Important! here is the cid reffered to the cid that i previously set on the code! -->
<hr>
some text
```

Now it works perfectly.