# Show an image when using cfmail?

Tags: coldfusion, cfmail

I'm trying to show an image when sending an email. Sending the email works, but in the image it shows blank. I know the 'src' URL is correct because I have it in other places and it shows.
How can I get it to work when sending an email?

```
<CFMAIL TO="email"
        FROM="email"
        SUBJECT="test"
        TYPE="HTML">
        <table>
        <tr><img src="icon_star.gif" alt="star" width="10" height="10">
            <td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">   <strong>Rising Star Award: #risingstar#</strong></font></td>
            <td valign="top" ><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2"><strong>#risingstar_ave#</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        ....more code ...
```

Comment: You need to use the full src url

Comment: You may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your image needs to be available via a full url.

```
<img src="http://www.MyDomain.com/images/icon_star.gif" 
    alt="star" 
    width="10" 
    height="10">
```

Answer (score 4):

you'll need an absolute path to the file so it can find it when the person opens their email.

**example:**

```
<img src="http://monkeysite.com/icon_star.gif" alt="star" width="10" height="10">
```

Comment: Frank, I think I beat your answer by 10 seconds.

Comment: You came in at 21:15:30 mine...21:14:32 (58 second ahead of you), but who's counting. Matt actually had 'an answer' before either of us' minus the example (as a comment). Either way I am ok with all this...Sometimes you get that sweet green check mark next your answer and sometimes you don't :)