# Problems with showing images from disk in HTML

Tags: html, axapta

I have html document given by email html body (it starts with html xmlns:v= ).

I am showing this in HTML form control. In that are some images. The images with src on internet are shown correctly. but there are some images on disk which are not shown

```
img border=0 width=16 height=16 id="Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01CF84AD.48503B60".
```

I am seting the path to the files by WinApi::setCurrentDirectory (and images are in right folder) but it does not help. What else I should set?

Images from internet are shown correctly.

Comment: Would you be able to use a relative or direct filepath? Those are the easiest way to create file paths imho. I dont know enough about WinApi to diagnose your issue unfortunately :(, just trying to add what input I can

Comment: The html is not mine I am just trying to show it. I have full path.

Comment: If the full path is available then I would use the full path to reference it with src, should be more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Axapta HTML control does not support showing embedded images.

See also [How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email).