# How to embed a picture (jpg/png/etc,) into html and email it out with mail

Tags: html, email

**Background:** I am trying to my emails html based, as it is more versatile (I am new to html). I have been playing around with html for a few hours. I can so far embed tables, and different headings and links etc. into the emails that I send out, but have massive difficulty with embedding pictures.

I thought it might a client specific problem - but Hotmail, Outlook and G-mail all don't show the attached image. All I see is the the box with the alt (*alternative*) text.

```
#!/bin/bash
h_test=mytest.html

echo "This is a test email"> TESTEMAILTESTEMAILTESTEMAIL.txt

echo "<html> 
<head>
<title>HTML E-mail</title>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This is just a test email.</p>
<p>Trying to do different things all in one email.</p>


<h2>Table 1</h2>
<table style="width:25%">
  <tr>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>UNITED STATE OF AMERICA</td>        
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sydney</td>
    <td>AUSTRALIA</td>      
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Istanbul</td>
    <td>TURKEY</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Table 2</h2>
<table border="1"; style="width:50%">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<h2>Image 1</h2>
<img src='https://www.google.com.au/search?q=image+test&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=663&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1_fn1MrNyAIVITamCh32cQej#imgrc=driDe9TNSAxoAM%3A' alt='You should be seeing a picture'>

<h2>Link</h2>

<a href='http://www.google.com'>Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>" > $h_test

echo ">> Sending email..."

`mail -s "$(echo -e "This is Subject\nContent-Type: text/html")" my_email@me.com  <  mytest.html`

echo "...e-mail sent"
```

**Research:** I have looked at [websites](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp) such as [this](http://learnwebcode.com/how-to-insert-an-image-in-xhtml/) site, but didn't work. I have also looked up similiar questions on [stackexchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312687/how-to-embed-images-in-email/4312865#4312865) but couldn't make it work.

**Q:** How can I embed pictures into my emails?

Comment: Did you try with an SVG instead?

Comment: You need to provide a URL to an image in the `src` attribute, not the URL to a web page that contains some images.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 I've tried direct link such as: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg

I have also tried to `src` a picture from a directory with different extensions (jpg, png, svg, bmp, etc.) all didn't work.

I've sent the email to different email clients - hoping it would be a client related issue..

Comment: @Michaelhomer I've tried a direct link to pictures as well such as "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"  alongside sourcing an image from a directory

Comment: Some email clients do not display remote images by default, due to privacy concerns.

Answer (score 3):

You can embed images in the html it self,base64-encoded, like this:

```
<img  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg....." />
```

Look for example at this  site to generate the base64 endoding: http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

**Update:**
I have now learned that this does not work in all email-clients:
Some examples:

- iOS Mail     **Yes**
- Outlook 2003 **Yes**
- Outlook 2007+    **No**
- Apple Mail   **Yes**
- Yahoo! Mail  **No**
- Gmail    **No**
- Android default  **Yes**

from this link https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/

Answer (score 0):

You are using the URL `https://www.google.com.au/search?q=image+test&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=663&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1_fn1MrNyAIVITamCh32cQej#imgrc=driDe9TNSAxoAM%3A` which is the URL to **an HTML document**.

You need to use the URL to an image!

---

Note that most email clients will prompt users before displaying images on external URLs.

You can avoid this by attaching the image (i.e. sending a multipart MIME email) and then using the `cid:` URL scheme to point to the attachment.

Alternatively, you can convert the image to a `data:` URL scheme and embed it directly in the URL.