# How can I prevent a referenced PNG from being squashed when added to an email via html?

Tags: outlook, size, png, image-resizing, mailitem

I've got this code to send an email which references an image on the internet:

```
private void EmailSheet(PricePushFile ppf)
{
    string emailAddr = GetEmailAddressForUnit(ppf.SourceFileName);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
    mailItem.To = emailAddr;
    string customer = GetCustomerName(ppf.SourceFileName);
    mailItem.Subject = string.Format("PRO*ACT Price Push – {0}", customer);

    List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
        {
            "<html><body><img src=\"http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Pro*Act logo\" ><p>Your PRO*ACT Price Push report is attached.</p>",
            "</body></html>"
        };
    mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, htmlBody.ToArray());

    mailItem.Attachments.Add(ppf.SourceFileName);
    mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
    mailItem.Display(false);
    mailItem.Send(); // This sends the email without a dialog displaying first
}
```

The png referenced (http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png) is fairly large, but when the email is sent, it is squashed down to pitiful puniness:

[image]

How can I ensure that the image displays full-sized, rather than squished, in the email?

### UPDATE

Adding the explicit sizes works fine, but the preferred "Base64" route didn't work; I tried this:

```
private static String PROACT_LOGO_BINARY = 
    "iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN. . .2ytlR8BYrxuzvr/AM6ZTOQUGb1+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

. . .

string proactLogoAsBinary = PROACT_LOGO_BINARY;
List<String> htmlBody = new List<string>
{
    String.Format("<html><body><img src=\"data:image/png;base64,{0}\" alt=\"Pro*Act logo\" ><p>Your PRO*ACT reports are attached.</p></body></html>", proactLogoAsBinary)
};
mailItem.HTMLBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, htmlBody.ToArray());
```

...and I get a "broken image" replacement image (little red ex)

Note: I got the binary via [this](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker):

Comment: Any chance you could get a rendered message and slap it in a pastebin or similar?  I don't see anything obviously wrong and would love to see how it's rendered by web browsers and other MUAs.  I've not heard of this technique failing anywhere, but Outlook has always been a bit of an outlier with regard to MUAs...

Comment: There is no message; it simply displays the "I can't make heads or tails out of that image you're trying to slap in there" icon instead of the wonderfully beaudacious image.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear.  If your MUA has a "view source" option, use it to get the underlying message as rendered by your code and pastebin that.  It'll have headers and all that jazz.  Or just shoot me a test message if you're comfy with that to bj .at. wjblack .dot. com and I'll see what thunderbird does with it.

Comment: Thanks, but I see no “View Source” option in Outlook (which I assume is my “MUA”). When I tried to send it to you, I got, "Cannot send this item"

Comment: Quoting http://superuser.com/questions/476940/outlook-2013-view-raw-message-source-of-an-email:

On the Message ribbon, select Action | Other actions | View source

I'm guessing something in the HTML that your code is rendering is wonky.  A sample will help diagnose that immensely.

Comment: I saw no "Action" there, but then read in the linked message in SuperUser, "Open the particular email in a new window by double-clicking on the message in the message list. (This is important, it's not enough to be just looking at the message in what Outlook calls the 'reading pane'.)" I don't know what that "message list" is, or where to find it. It (the open email to be sent) is not in my "Drafts" folder, and there is nothing in my Outbox. This is Outlook 2007, BTW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121400/discussion-between-bj-black-and-b-clay-shannon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will likely vary from MUA to MUA (I think you're looking at Outlook there; you know there are other email clients, right? ;-) ).

Anyways, I'd consider a couple of things:

1. Given a vacuum of height/width data, an HTML renderer could decide to just render some default size.  Try adding actual height and width to your IMG tag:

   `<img src="..." height="130" width="199"...>`
2. This is just a logo (and a tiny file), so you should probably consider embedding it into your message instead (modern MUAs really don't like auto-retrieving remote resources by default and give users a "do you want to download things from foo.com"-type messages--so many of your users will either have to whitelist you or not see your logo at all).  See the answer here: [Embed Base64 PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207530/6664886)

Since you can just encode the file one-time to base64 and copypasta it into your HTML source, it shouldn't be too painful (and it will get viewed by way more recipients than an external link).

Comment: Please see my Update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly set the image dimensions so that the email client will know how big you want the image to display.

In your case, the image is 199 x 130, so add width=199, height=130

http://www.proactusa.com/wp-content/themes/proact/images/pa_logo_notag.png\" alt=\"Pro*Act logo\" width=\"199\" height=\"130\" >