# Sending aws cli SES as a file attachmennt

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ses

I am trying to send my file as an attachment in my `AWS SES` via `AWS CLI`. 
Given below is the `message.json` sample provided by aws documentation

```
{
   "Data": "From: sender@example.com\nTo: recipient@example.com\nSubject: Test email sent using the AWS CLI (contains an attachment)\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: Multipart/Mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nThis is the message body.\n\n--NextPart\nContent-Type: text/plain;\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.txt\"\n\nThis is the text in the attachment.\n\n--NextPart--"
}
```

Where do I add path of the attachment file needed to this `json`
Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey Sri, how abt this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the attachment file to `Base64` and use it in the `json` body.

Example:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="filename.extension" Content-Description: filename.extension Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.ext"; Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

\n\nbase-64-text-body\n\n--
```

You can use `Python` or `node.js` code to convert it automatically for you.

Comment: where is the path? i dont see it