# Embedding images into email using shell script

Tags: shell, sendmail

I have a shell script that echoes html and then I need to attach some dynamically generated graphs(using matplotlib) into the emails that I am sending.

The images resides in the same directory as the shell script.

I tried the simple approach of `<img src="file.jpg"></img>` but the emails that I received did not show images.How to go about doing this so that images appear inline?

```
echo "</table><img src=\"citywise.png\"><P><img src=\"fivesec.png\"><P><img src=\"ten.png\"><P><img src=\"fifteen.png\"><P><img src=\"thrty.png\"><P><img src="sixty.png"><P><img src=\"gtsixty.png\"><P><img src=\"hits.png\"></body></html>">>htTimernew.tsv


/usr/sbin/sendmail sankalp.jain@example.com < htTimernew.tsv
```

Answer (score 1):

The recipients couldn't see the images in your email because it doesn't include them.

Try this: [embedding image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)