# How to Include the content of html page with images in jenkins email content

Tags: jenkins

How to Include the content of  html page with images in jenkins email content

Im using editable email notification and converted the img with base64.
But when i receive the email image is not getting displayed.
Note: when i try to open html page locally I m able to see image.
But not in the email.

Answer (score 1):

it is not jenkins related. It's properly email client issue. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email) question how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Believe me, all you need is to install a useful plugin called [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)

Answer (score -1):

Finally after long search I was able to see the image in my outlook.
I used cid in img tag and attached the images

Comment: could please share the solution