# How to send an email using client side gmail API which have html content and an image as attachment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mime-types, email-attachments, gmail-api

> This is my code and I am not receiving html ,only attachment is visible ,if I remove code of attachment then html is received in mail ,I have tried various MIME layouts including relative and alternative,i want both html and and attachment in mail .

```
   var accessToken = $rootScope.accessToken;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var encodedMail =btoa(
      "Subject: "+subject+"\r\n" +
      "From: "sender@xyz.com"\r\n" +
      "To: "receiver@xyz.com"\r\n" +
      "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"foo_mixed_ bar\"\r\n\r\n" +
      "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
              "<div style=\"width:700px; height:55px; background:red; \">hello this is html content</div>"+"\n"+
              "--foo_mixed_ bar\n"+
       "Content-Type: image/png;charset=UTF-8\n" +
       "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"+
       "Content-Disposition: attachment ; filename=\"example.png\"\n\n "+
             <png data>+"\n\n"+
             "--foo_mixed_ bar--"



    ).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');



    deferred.resolve($.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: JSON.stringify({
        'raw': encodedMail
      })
    }));
    return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message has to be `multipart/mixed` with a `text/html`-part and an `image/png`-part.

You can use the [simple upload URL](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple) instead. Then you don't have to encode the message and you can use a message up to 25 mb in size. If you do this, the content type of the entire payload will just be `message/rfc822`.

```
function sendMessage() {
  var accessToken = $rootScope.accessToken;
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var sender = 'emtholin@gmail.com';
  var receiver = 'emtholin@gmail.com';
  var subject = 'Example Subject';
  var smileyIconPng = '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';
  var messageText = 'This is the messsage text';
  var message = [
    'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"', '\r\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0', '\r\n',
    'From: ', sender, '\r\n',
    'To: ', receiver, '\r\n',
    'Subject: ', subject, '\r\n\r\n',

    '--foo_bar_baz', '\r\n',
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"', '\r\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0', '\r\n',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit', '\r\n\r\n',

    '<div style="width:700px; height:55px; background:red;">', messageText, '</div>', '\r\n\r\n',

    '--foo_bar_baz', '\r\n',
    'Content-Type: image/png', '\r\n',
    'MIME-Version: 1.0', '\r\n',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64', '\r\n',
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.png"', '\r\n\r\n',

    smileyIconPng, '\r\n\r\n',

    '--foo_bar_baz--'
  ].join('');

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart",
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    },
    contentType: "message/rfc822",
    data: message
  }).then(deferred.resolve);
}

sendMessage().then(function () {
  console.log('Message sent successfully!');
});
```

**Resulting message**
[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i tried other way and it worked , I uploaded my file on drive and gave link of drive in html ,that file automatically showed up in attachment in mail.

Comment: @Tholle, Hi, what needs to be done to add that image inline instead of an attachment?

Comment: @KarthikBose You could check the answers to [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email).

Comment: thank you, wondering, which god whispered all the above into your head, because [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) is a joke!