# send image in mail body using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to embed an image in the mail body using javascript and jquery:

```
function SendEmail(StudyMail) {
     var emailBodyContent = "<span> " + greating + "</span> ,\n\n";
     emailBodyContent += " <img src=\"images/1.png\" />";
      DivMailBody.html(emailBodyContent);

        var body = DivMailBody.text();

        var contents = "".concat('mailto:' + StudyMail, '?subject= A new study', '&body=', encodeURIComponent(body));

        var pwin = window.open(contents, "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, width=100, height=100");
        try {
            setTimeout(function () {
                pwin.close();
            }, 100);
        } catch (e) {
        }
}
```

it sends the mail without the image.

Comment: You need to provide full url of the image in email body. Relative path won't work.

Comment: when debug var body = DivMailBody.text(); 
it does not contain any image tag

Answer (score 0):

You must you image tag like below and emmbed your image inside your html page

```
<img src=\"cid:filename\">
```

for embedding image you can use the following linke

[embedding image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)