# Embed html with image path in Gmail with python

Tags: python, selenium, gmail, html-email, mailgun

I am making a notification system which sends emails with a html table which has images.

the images shows up fine in the actual page.
I am grabbing the table source with selenium (changing all relative paths to full paths)

```
    for attr in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="mainTable"]/tbody/tr[contains(@id, "cell_")]'):

        #gettin the image link

        imgattr = attr.find_element_by_xpath('.//td[4]/a[1]/img[1]')
        imglink = imgattr.get_attribute('src')

        #changing to full path and setting that with javascript

        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("src","{}");'.format(urljoin(root_url, imglink)), imgattr)
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("width","{}");'.format('72'), imgattr)
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("height","{}");'.format('54'), imgattr)

        #getting the element (table) again 
        #with image links changed to full path

        elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table[@id="mainTable"]')
        resp = elem.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

*now i am using mailgun api to send a email*

```
    r = requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/version/my domain name/messages",
    auth=("api", "my api key"),
    data={"from": "mailgun@mydomain",
    "to": ["recipient1@gmail.com", "recipient2@gmail.com"],
    "subject": "random subject",
    "html": resp})
```

*email gets sent no issues but the images dont how, their links change when sent in email*
**example Actual Page**
[image]

***Sent email inspect element, links change from source to a blank one***
[image]

Basically the image changes from this:

```
<img src="https://p3.aleado.com/pic/?system=auto&amp;date=2019-11-07&amp;auct=243&amp;bid=70048&amp;number=1&amp;w=72" load_src="https://p3.aleado.com/pic/?system=auto&amp;date=2019-11-07&amp;auct=243&amp;bid=70048&amp;number=1&amp;w=72" border="0" name="img_preview" width="72">
```

To this:

```
<img src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/qQR9p1-B2oWM3V-bVJssDVajsvZN9irPqHctNMUr6jTsgKmuZFP30fcTB54a-wtpM_H6rL0K_Fz7huR4oMPVTISpvE7XSJkwwFbFMZc6B2yVviL28WMGzAXGzlso8RHgGTjxGwqGS7_XAQ=s0-d-e1-ft#https://p3.aleado.com/pic/?system=auto&amp;date=2019-11-07&amp;auct=243&amp;bid=70048&amp;number=1&amp;w=72" name="m_-9099380790990105554_img_preview" class="CToWUd" width="72" border="0">
```

*I have tried Base64 but Gmail doesn't support it and show blanks in its place*

What am i doing wrong here and how can i embed those links?

any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you are doing anything wrong. By default Gmail downloads all the images and places it on a proxy server. When the images are served, its faster as its already on Gmail servers.According to Litmus the proxy first started in 2013.

> When an image is cached, it is downloaded from the original server and
>   stored on a proxy server. Subsequent views of the cached image will
>   always display from the proxy server rather than the original server,
>   effectively re-routing all the image downloads along with the
>   associated tracking data that comes with the image download.

You can read the full article from Litmus [here](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-adds-image-caching-what-you-need-to-know).

Comment: ahh i see, any suggestions on how can i embed images and why they are not working ?

Comment: @ShantanuShady Embedding images in emails can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email). Just a quick note. Those embedded images might show up as attachments in Gmail if they are accepted and shown.