# Send Image to email using nextjs and renderToString on the API routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, sendgrid

I want to send emails styled and to contain images.

I am using `renderToString` method to pass props into the component. Everything works in the API routes.

```
mport client from "@/lib/prisma";


import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import Quotes from "@/pages/emails/Quotes/Quotes";
import { sendEmailHTML } from "@/lib/SendEmail/sendEmail";


export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { email, firstName, lastName, phone, message } = req.body;
    
    try {
            // Pass the props here
            const emailTemplate = renderToString(<Quotes clientEmail={email} firstName={firstName} lastName={lastName} phone={phone} message={message} />);


            await client.Quote.create({ data: { email, firstName, lastName, 
                phone: `0${phone}`, 
                message } });
            res.status(201).send('Quote created');

            await sendEmailHTML('New quote', emailTemplate);
        } 

        catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({error});
        }
}
```

The Quotes component get the props and apply the styles (just something to see it working). But the image is not working... Is the method a problem?

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import React from 'react'

const Quotes = props => {


  const mailMainWrapper = {
    backgroundColor: 'green '
  }

  const styling = {color: 'blue', fontWeight: 'bolder'}


  return (
    <main className={mailMainWrapper}>
      <Image src='https://source.unsplash.com/zTNv5fteUWI' width={200} height={120} alt='jbaofb' />
        <div style={mailMainWrapper}>
          <p style={styling}>Client email:    { props.clientEmail } </p>
          <p>Full name:       { props.firstName + ' ' + props.lastName} </p>
          <p>Contact number:  { props.phone } </p>
          <p>Message          { props.message } </p>
        </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, next/image tries to fetch an image. so you have to handle the image "manually". What I would recommend would be using the img element and setting the src prop to a base64 encoded string (which does not work everywhere - but how the image is displayed on a multitude of email clients is important.)

Please keep in mind that setting a max size is important as the size of the email is...

Adding images to HTML email alone is quite difficult as per [embedding image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)

As far as I understood there is no proper solution.

Personally I create a email and use https://app.postdrop.io/ to test send it to multiple email addresses and verify the intended behaviour....