# Image in HTML email

Tags: html, html-email

I'm not able to put an image in my email made with HTML, the image appears on the live server but it's not appearing in the email, I'm testing it in outlook, I've already put the image on the web and call it by its URL but it still doesn't appear I don't know what's wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center;">
                <table style="background-color: #5200FF; height: 100px; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="https://d.img.vision/datafit/logoWhite.png" alt="Logo" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p style="color: #404040; font-family: 'sansationbold', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; margin: 30px; padding: 10px; text-align: center;">Olá {{ nome }}!</p>
                            <p style="color: #404040; font-family: 'sansationbold', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; margin: 30px; padding: 10px; text-align: center;">Recebemos uma solicitação para redefinir a senha da sua conta na DataFit. Para continuar com o processo de redefinição de senha, por favor, clique no link abaixo</p>
                            <div style="margin: 30px; text-align: center;">
                                <a href="{{ reset_password_url }}" style="background-color: #5200FF; border: none; border-radius: 5px; color: #FFFFFF; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block;  font-family: 'sansationbold', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; margin: 0; padding: 20px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">
                                    Clique aqui para redefinir sua senha
                                </a>
                            </div>                            
                            <div style="margin: 30px; text-align: center;">
                                <p style="color: #404040; font-family: 'sansationbold', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 5px; text-align: center;">Obrigado,</p>
                                <p style="color: #404040; font-family: 'sansationbold', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; margin: 5px; text-align: center;">Equipe DataFit</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table style="background-color: #5200FF; height: 50px; width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>                      
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to put the image via the url but it didn't work

Comment: Which image? https://d.img.vision/datafit/logoWhite.png ? Or another?

Comment: Yes, this image. <img src="https://d.img.vision/datafit/logoWhite.png" alt="Logo" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;"/>

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! there are 2 solutions im aware of: 1) use base64 encoded format; 2) use attachment `cid`; however remember to keep the email size small (around 5MB-ish) to maintain compatibility with most mail client. it is also a good idea to consider alternate view by providing plain text format message for the email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [embedding image in html email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706891/embedding-image-in-html-email)

Comment: I don't know if base64 is a good option, I saw people say that Outlook doesn't support it, I thought the best way was to use the URL, I saw several places and tutorials doing it like this but I don't know why mine isn't working

Comment: anything that doesnt work stems on security reasons. url is also kinda bad for you can put anything in it to trigger a http request risking some privacy and some older browser are exploitable with certain magic bytes. thats why base64 was an option, the email service provider can scan the image on premise. but base64 is not without its own issue as some base64 decoder succeptible to buffer overflow (forgot the CVE, but its there). thats why i put the second option, use `cid`. you cant cover it with only html its complicated and not accessible if you dont program stuff. so, did you code?

Comment: *"you can put anything in it to trigger a http request risking some privacy"* - analytics often call these tracking pixel. but i digress, there are a lot of items to discuss on a simple "sending email" stuff.

Comment: i saw `{{` on your html. if its laravel, you can consider [Inline Attachment](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#inline-attachments). please tag your question properly so we dont have to deal with guessing the technology stack.

Comment: It's django, I didn't add the framework because it's not relevant to the question, I just want to resolve the image attachment in the email

Comment: I'll try to put the image inside an A tag.

Comment: *"because it's not relevant to the question"* - it **is** relevant if you want to implement solution number 2.

Answer (score 0):

The image URL coded in the example provided, `https://d.img.vision/datafit/logoWhite.png` , is not accessible. I'm late to this question so perhaps it has since been removed from the server because I'd imagine these good folks checked the URL before commenting. Assuming the image is accessible, not massive, and not corrupted in some way, I don't see why it wouldn't render. I replaced the inaccessible image URL with another and it displays as expected across all the 20 so Outlook email clients my testing tool has available.