# Adding embedded images within mail body phpmailer class

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Im trying to embed an image within my message body but it ends up as an attachment

```
    $mailer->Subject = APP_NAME . " - " . $name . " send you and Ad : " . $row['name'];
    $mailer->IsHTML(true);
    $mailer->AddEmbeddedImage('../images/namDiams.png', 'logoimg', 'namDimes.png'); 

    //footer
    $footer = "Regards<br/><br/>";
    $footer .= '<table style="width: 95%">';
    $footer .= '<tr>';
    $footer .= '<td>';
    $footer .= "<strong><span style='font-size: 15px'>NamDimes Team</span></strong><br/>
                    NamDimes<br/>
                    Contact Number: " . APP_CONTACT . "<br/>
                    Email: " . APP_EMAIL . "<br/>
                    Website: " . APP_WEBSITE . "<br/>";
    $footer .= '</td>';
    $footer .= '<td style="text-align:right">';
    $footer .= '<img src=\"cid:logoimg\" />';
    $footer .= '</td>';
    $footer .= '</tr>';
    $footer .= '</table>';

    $mailer->Body = $body . $footer;
    $mailer->AltBody="This is text only alternative body.";
    $mailer->AddAttachment('../' . $row['image_path'], $row['name'] . ".jpg");
```

i have set everything else, including the addresses, the mail gets send out, logo image that I want embed in the body gets attached as an attachment, anyone know why?

Comment: You code seems to work. Be sure to have latest PHPmailer version. By the way, IMHO you should use external images and not embedded ones.

Comment: i dont get you on the externel images part, kind of new to this

Comment: just plain `http://` links. Just like `http://your.site.com/img/mypic.png`

Comment: the src attribute is removed if i do this

Comment: Embedded images vs external images are two completely different things – if you want to make sure the image gets displayed in as many mail clients as possible, you should stick with embedded images – because external images are highly likely to get blocked to avoid user tracking.

Comment: And what about removing backslashes in the img src? like this `$footer .= '<img src="cid:logoimg" />';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `$mailer->AddEmbeddedImage`, but directly add

`<img src="http://.../images/namDiams.png" />` instead.

The mail length should be lighter... And it works.

**EDIT**

I don't know if it will help you but there is a little mistake here :

```
$mailer->AddEmbeddedImage('../images/namDiams.png', 'logoimg', 'namDimes.png');
```

Should be

```
$mailer->AddEmbeddedImage('../images/namDiams.png', 'logoimg', 'namDiames.png');//the last param the second 'a' was missing...
```

Another topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851728/how-to-embed-images-in-html-email)

Comment: some how the src attribute is removed from the img tag if i do this

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that user2189925's answer does work. However, I use the absolute path since the location of the calling script is more likely to change than the location of the image.

e.g.

```
<img src="C:\folder\images\namDiames.png" />
```

Comment: Pointing to a local file on your harddrive will never show up in the actual e-mail. So this will never work.

Comment: This worked for me. PHPMailer was smart enough to embed the image in the email by replacing the value of the `src` attribute with the actual source data of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem, then I decided to replace the following

```
<img src="img/example.jpg"
```

with

```
<img src= "https://mysitename.com/img/example.jpg">
```

and it worked.

Answer (score -3):

just give path of your image to the mail body eg: (img src="../images/cat.jpeg) it will definately work