# PhpMailer not embedding image in mail body but attaching

Tags: php, wordpress, email, phpmailer

I am sending email using PHPmailer and tying to embed image in mail body (using CID method `<img src="cid:qrcode" />`)  but it always attaching image instead of embedding.Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code (commented lines in code, already tried. ).

Here is the screenshot of my code [image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. It means it's not searchable, editable, or copyable for anyone wanting to show you amendments.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you're using a very old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on a very old example. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

The other obvious problem is that while you're putting HTML into `Body`, you've commented out the call to `isHTML()`, so your message is being sent as plain text, which has no concept of displaying images inline. Uncomment this line:

```
$mail->isHTML();
```

Also bear in mind that in MIME there is essentially no difference between attachments and inline images - everything is an attachment, it's just that some attachments may be referred to from HTML parts, and HTML-capable clients can make use of that linkage.

If Outlook is removing `src` attributes, that's clearly not your sending code's problem. Outlook does some very unpleasant things to email.

One other minor thing: instead of `dirname(__FILE__)` you can use `__DIR__` in any current version of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

just as an assistance I encountered the same problem and after much mumbling arrived at a solution which might help others.

1. Tried dumping the image in the same folder - nope
2. Tried **DIR** variable to dynamicalyly pull in the image - nope

Finally, hardcoded the path to the folder in which my embedded image lived, hurrah

Magic forumla for me (using PHPmailer v5.5) - note I'm using Plesk so your definitive path may differ, use mine as a guide...

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("/var/www/vhosts/{domainname}/httpdocs/{foldername)/image.jpg", "emailimg", "image.jpg");

I note that when calling in the image as an embedded image that i had to use the same filename as I think PHPmailer uses the structure:

embedded-img-name source, reference id, embedded-img-name within the internal  AddEmbeddedImage call

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i think it will work for you

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/2u_cs_mini.jpg', 'logo_2u');
```

and on the  tag put src='cid:logo_2u'

Comment: You can add this code under your body tag, its work i am already using this

Comment: I just used these two line
 ` $mail->Body = "Embedded Image src='cid:logo_2u' ";
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.jpeg', 'logo_2u');
   ` and same issue.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518703/adding-embedded-images-within-mail-body-phpmailer-class

Comment: I already checked & tried this post. if we use img tag, gmail or outlook remove src .I have also tried by chaging content type , adding headers etc but nothing working. image is getting attached always.

Comment: `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  
    

    $mail->isSMTP();  
  
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;  
    $mail->setFrom('test@mytest.com', 'Chris1111');  
    $mail->addAddress('test@test.com');  
    $mail->isHTML(true);  
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('footer.jpeg', 'logoimg');  
    
    $mail->Body = "<h1>Test 1 of phpmailer </h1>  
    <p>This is test Picture: <img src=\"cid:logoimg\" /></p>";  
    $mail->AltBody = "This is the text only alternative body";  
    $mail->send();  
    echo 'Message has been sent!';`

Comment: still same issue